# Aha! So elegant!

Tags: visual, rebus

The image below is made up by these 4 different things as you can see. 
The answer consists of 5 characters.

What does it represent?

[image]

Hint(related to image 1)

> A number, a triangle, a polygon

Hint2(related to one of the remaining 3 images)

> D, I, L etc...

Hint3(related to image 4)

> A letter and a number

Hint4(related to image 1 again, since this one probably is the hardest one)

> grey(nr), yellow, yellow

Comment: Boivbhfyl abg gur pbeerpg nafjre, ohg pbhyq or "qensg" (qrterr bs pheingher be n fxrgpu,n cyna, n zrnfher bs n qvfgnapr, n onax cnlzrag (rt gubhfnaq Fbhgu Nsevpna Enaq), sybj, pheerag,n qvfgnapr bs jngreyvar..naq gur jubyr guvat vf nyfb n qensg: n qrfvta.)

Comment: No, its a completely different answer!

Comment: Added some new info to guide you in the right direction

Comment: I think I've figured out the first two characters (first two images), maybe, but still stuck on the second half.

Comment: Maybe you have. Also, keep in mind that only one of the 4 images represent two characters(since the answer is 5 characters)!

Comment: @Prim3numbah - I think you need at least one more tag for this puzzle, such as 'mathematical', based on what one must do to solve it.

Comment: @Lanny Strack Yes, maybe mathematical knowledge or similar(for the first image)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a tip of the hat to Rand, the answer is:

> E=mc2 (that's a squared)

I interpret the pictures as follows:

## 1

> E (The three objects are '14' and a triangle 'base' and '16' vertices. 14 in base 16 is 'E'.)

## 2

> = (as Rand noted, a set of scales indicating an 'equal' reading).

## 3

> M (the output of the function Roman(1000))

## 4

> c squared (a picture of the 'sea' placed within a square, thereby being 'squared')

Comment: This is the correct answer and reasoning. Good job!

Comment: This one sounds concrete

Comment: Darn, good job. I'd thought this was probably going to be the answer, but then I had to do some other things before coming back to think about how to get that from the clues.

Answer (score 4):

I think the first image is

> $\pi$. The image consists of a triangle ($3$ sides), a number ($14$), and a hexadecagon ($16$ sides). Putting them together gives $3,14,16$: the start of the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

The second image might be

> $=$. It shows a balanced set of scales, both sides of *equal* weight.

The third image is probably

> the one that gives two different characters in the solution, since there are clearly two different parts to this. 1000 might be interpreted in Roman numerals as $M$, or in prefix unit notation as $k$ (kilo).

The fourth image should be

> $C$, because the image shows a *sea*.

Overall that gives

> $\pi=RMC$ or $\pi=RkC$. This is five characters, but it doesn't make sense yet. Probably we need to do something else with ... my guess would be the third image.

Comment: This is not the correct answer but you're actually close though(except on the 1st image). Also, the only image representing 2 characters is image4("a letter and a number")